# php paragraph convert to tags separate words

Tags: php, tags

I have paragraph or words like: `$title = "stack over flow is good site"`

I want it in tags like : `stack, over, flow , is, good, site`

```
<? echo strtolower( $title); ?>
```

In php which function i use?

Comment: `$tags = explode(' ', $text);`, which will give you an array of each word. You might also want to remove any non-alphanumeric characters as well.

Comment: How to remove non-alphanumeric characters like :is: etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should work for you.

> ```
> <? echo strtolower(str_replace(" ", ",", $title)); ?>
> ```

Or you can try

```
<? echo implode(', ', explode(" ", strtolower($title))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the keywords in a string like that, you can use `str_replace` like so:

```
$title = str_replace( $title, " ", ", " );
```

If you want the keywords in an array to display for example HTML elements, you can use `explode`:

```
$keywords = explode( " ", $title );
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$tags = explode(' ', strtolower( $title));
print_r($tags);
```

Comment: its work like this  Array ( [0] => reflection [1] => of [2] => the [3] => forest [4] => hdr [5] => 1080p )

Answer (score 0):

First split the string with 
    $array =    preg_split("/ /",$title);

Then you can do what ever you want with the array
for example

```
foreach($array as $word){
    echo "<div>$word</div>";
}
```